# Show lists on 2 levels in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a file as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{A Section}
body

\begin{figure}
abc
\caption{a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}{l}
efg
\caption{a table}
\end{table}

\newpage
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

It compiles well. However, in the table of contents, `List of Figures` and `List of Tables` are not shown (please ignore the font and background colours).

[image]

Could anyone tell me how to let these 2 lists appear in the table of contents? Additionally, I would like to see 2 levels as follows: `Lists` on the first level, and all the lists on the second level, is it possible?

```
Lists                                               3
   List of Figures                                  3
   List of Tables                                   4
```

Comment: Add `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{List of figures}` after `\listoffigures`. Is that what you want? You may also use `\usepackage{tocbibind}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{A Section}
body

\begin{figure}
abc
\caption{a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}{l}
efg
\caption{a table}
\end{table}

\newpage
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Lists}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}\listtablename}
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

---

### EDIT

If you want to add dashed lines only for those entries, load the `tocloft` package and issue

```
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{\_}
```

in the preamble and

```
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsecleader}{\protect\cftdotfill{\protect\cftdotsep}}}
```

at the right point and then

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsecleader}{\protect\hfill}}
```

when they are not needed anymore, as in the following example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{\_}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{A Section}
body

\begin{figure}
abc
\caption{a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}{l}
efg
\caption{a table}
\end{table}

\newpage
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Lists}
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsecleader}{\protect\cftdotfill{\protect\cftdotsep}}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}\listtablename}
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsecleader}{\protect\hfill}}
\section{Another section}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Otherwise, omit

```
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{\_}
```

and you will have dotted lines which, in my opinion, look better

[image]

---

### EDIT #2

If you want that behavior for all entries, simply issue

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

in the preamble, depending on what you want.

This is an example with dotted lines

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{A Section}
body

\begin{figure}
abc
\caption{a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}{l}
efg
\caption{a table}
\end{table}

\newpage
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Lists}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}\listtablename}
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\section{Another section}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you... Is it possible to added dash line between `List of Figures` and `3` (and `List of Tables` and `4`)?

Comment: @SoftTimur Yes, see the edit.

Comment: Sorry... what you put is full line, whereas I wanted `dash`/`dotted` line...

Comment: @SoftTimur There is a possibility with dotted lines in the answer. Dashed lines will look really ugly, in my opinion.

Comment: @SoftTimur Anyway I've added a possibility with dashed lines, too...